# android difference between autocompletetextview and search view?

Tags: android

I want to provide suggestions from a sqlite database when user type in a text box. my understanding is that if you want to start a new activity then use search view, else use autocompletetextview. they both can accomplish my task. Am i right?

Answer (score 1):

Both 'SearchView' and 'AutoCompleteTextView' are views, so it doesn't matter if your starting a new activity for either of them. The difference between them is that SearchView has a few additional abilities, such as the ability to connect a 'ContentProvider' to the view (like an SQLite database for example), whereas the AutoCompleteTextView is just an extended TextView control

Comment: what's the problem with ACTV and providing suggestions from SQLite database or any other Cursor based data source like ContentProvider?